# Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

```
@IBAction func displayResult(sender: AnyObject) {

    var area = (heightTextField.text as NSString).floatValue * (baseTextField.text as NSString).floatValue

    resultLabel.text = string(area)

}
```

The above code is giving me the error "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments".

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: What is `string(area)` with a lowercase "s"? You *did* copy/paste your real code, didn't you?

Comment: Yes this was another mistake on my code though the error went away when I replaced it with a string representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resultLabel.text = "(\area)"
```

Create a string representation instead.

Comment: It works fine with a string representation with the backslash before the parenthesis. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`String` should be capitalized.

```
resultLabel.text = String(area)
```